# delaying position attribute with transitions?

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to delay the position:relative; on hover within my CSS.

If I were to write something like this:

```
.uk-navbar-nav:hover > li {
  transition-delay:2s;
  position: relative;
  background-color:red;
}
```

the background-color would activate after 2 seconds, but not the position:relative.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049855/css-transitions-mixing-absolute-and-relative-positioning

Comment: Don't see a css way, you may need js.