# CSS transition-delay on display

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have an element. On hover it goes `opacity: 0;` in `500ms`. After `500ms` I need to make it to `display:none;`.

Is this possible by using `transition-delay` on the `display` property?

```
.myEl {
transition: opacity 500ms, display 0ms ease 500ms;
opacity: 1;
display: block;
}

.myEl:hover {
display:none;
opacity:0;
}
```

This code above doesn't work for me :(

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/onvpn995/

Comment: No, transitions may not be applied to the display property. You could alternatively use visibility.

Comment: You cannot transition the display property

Comment: The thing is i need it removed from the dom, maybe can i dealy set it to positoin absolute?

Comment: I recommend reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049855/css-transitions-mixing-absolute-and-relative-positioning

Comment: solution was to not use position or display but to use height new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/onvpn995/2/

Comment: Hey @Blagoh! Please post your solution as an answer and accept it so that this question is completed :)

Comment: Ok will do @misterManSam :)

Answer (score -3):

If you use "display:none"; you will not be able to have a transition.
You Can use following:

```
.myEl {
transition: opacity 500ms;
opacity: 1;
display: block;
}

.myEl:hover {
opacity: 0;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

(as visibility:hidden; has almost the same effect as display:none)

Comment: This will not have any transition, it will only hide the element