# Animate css, position, width & height on click

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have an app with a basic right sidebar/main content layout, like this:

```
<body>
<div class="sidebar">Sub nav</div>
<div class="main-content">Some content</div>
</body>
```

Generally the main content block will float left of the sidebar... pretty typical layout. 
However, I want to allow the user a click of some btn on the page that will maximize the main content area to fill the entire body. Essentially hiding everything behind it.

I can apply a class via jquery to give main-content some additional classes:

```
.main-content.maximize {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
etc...
}
```

but I would like to animate into the maximized display.

Please take note, I desire to animate main-content from a relative position to an absolute position.
An animation back to the original state would be required as well.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to think a little out of the box on this one, but came up with this final solution.

Instead of animating the main container with JS, I used JS to toggle classes on the container around the sidebar and main content area when a trigger is clicked, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.toggle-view', function() {
    $(".content .wrapper").toggleClass("full-width");
    $(this).toggleClass('full-view, standard-view');
});
```

When .wrapper gets .full-width, it activates a transition effect in the css:

- minimizing the width of the sidebar, and
- maximizing the width of the main container.

See a [working sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/trobbins26/3kstn0xa/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as already answered [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049855/css-transitions-mixing-absolute-and-relative-positioning), you can't animate between `relative` and `absolute` positioning.

What you can do, though, is to make the element absolutely positioned just before the animation and keep it in the same place on the screen, by using the offsets returned by [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/). And when you want to restore it back to its normal place, after the animation, do the reverse and go back to the initial position and remove the offsets.

If the element was *in-flow*, you'll also want to supply a placeholder of the same dimensions to keep its space occupied so that nothing else flows into that space.

I tried here to give you a rough idea of what can be done, but this should be adjusted to your particular situation as it won't work out of the box. Collapsing margins, floats, shifted position with relative positioning can each change particular parts of the solution.

Comment: The idea here seems promising, however I don't see any link to your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').click(function () {
    $(this).css({
        'width' : $(this).width()  * 1.1,     
        'height': $(this).height() * 1.1
    });
});
```