# JQuery add class and remove class div animation

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Some of div want to get full screen with animation. which means slowly full screen.

This is my div Code:

```
<div class="bg">
<div class=" col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-mxs-3 subcontents" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="180" id="affix2">
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" ><strong>aaa​</strong><a href="#" class="open1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full pull-right openicon" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>


Some contains

</div>
</div>
```

glyphicon-resize-full icons coming form bootstrap 3 css. when this icon click this div will be full screen. when again click it, that div come to default position. Now that is working for me. but I tried to add animation css code it is also not work.

JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".open1").on("click",function(){
        if($(".subcontents").hasClass("popup1")){
            $(".subcontents").removeClass("popup1"); 
            $(".bg").removeClass("bg1");
            $(".openicon").addClass("glyphicon-resize-full");
            $(".openicon").removeClass("glyphicon-resize-small");

        } else{
            $(".subcontents").addClass("popup1"); 
            $(".bg").addClass("bg1");
            $(".openicon").removeClass("glyphicon-resize-full");
            $(".openicon").addClass("glyphicon-resize-small");

        }
    });

});
```

CSS Code:

```
.popup1{
    position:fixed;
    top:1px;
    left:25%;
    width:50vw;
    height:90vh;
    z-index:1000;

}

.bg1{
    height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); z-index:999;
}
```

When that icon click popup1 and bg1 are add to subcontents and bg divs. which means subcontents come to middle and full screen and also background will be black by adding bg1. But can't animate that to see coming that div full screen and again going to default position.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".open1").on("click",function(){
        if($(".subcontents").hasClass("popup1")){
            $(".subcontents").removeClass("popup1"); 
            $(".bg").removeClass("bg1");
            $(".openicon").addClass("glyphicon-resize-full");
            $(".openicon").removeClass("glyphicon-resize-small");

        } else{
            $(".subcontents").addClass("popup1"); 
            $(".bg").addClass("bg1");
            $(".openicon").removeClass("glyphicon-resize-full");
            $(".openicon").addClass("glyphicon-resize-small");

        }
    });

});
```

```css
.popup1{
    position:fixed;
    top:1px;
    left:25%;
    width:50vw;
    height:90vh;
    z-index:1000;

}

.bg1{
    height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" />

<div class="bg">
<div class=" col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-mxs-3 subcontents" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="180" id="affix2">
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" ><strong>aaa​</strong><a href="#" class="open1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full pull-right openicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>Open</a></li>


Some contains

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create JSfiddle or codepen as well?

Comment: @SanjeevK https://jsfiddle.net/yxmbf0ry/3/ Bootstrap is not work but functions are working

Answer (score 3):

You can just add `transition : ease all .5s` for `bg1` class. it would work

Comment: this animation only for background not for coming middle or going default position. which means animation should be subcontents

Comment: css position animation will not work. please take a look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049855/css-transitions-mixing-absolute-and-relative-positioning

Answer (score 1):

The transition : ease all .5s; will help create the animation effect but will only animate the width. Then, creating another class called "la" with the height of 600px or whatever height you like will expand the height as well.

```
<style>
.popup1{
position:fixed;
top:1px;
left:25%;
width:50vw;
height:100%;
z-index:1000;
transition : ease all .5s;


}
.la{
  height:600px;
}


.bg1{
    height:600px;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background-         color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); z-index:999;
}

  </style>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".open1").on("click",function(){
        if($(".subcontents").hasClass("popup1")){
            $(".subcontents").removeClass("popup1"); 
            $(".bg").removeClass("bg1");
            $(".openicon").addClass("glyphicon-resize-full");
            $(".openicon").removeClass("glyphicon-resize-small");
             $("li").removeClass("la");


         } else{
             $(".subcontents").addClass("popup1"); 
             $(".bg").addClass("bg1");
             $(".openicon").removeClass("glyphicon-resize-full");
              $(".openicon").addClass("glyphicon-resize-small");
             $("li").addClass("la");

           }
      });

     });
```