# Transition between absolute placement workaround

Tags: css

I know transitioning between position: absolute; and position:relative; is impossible, but I really want to achieve a certain effect and need a workaround.

Basically: I have a series of buttons in a grid, so their position changes when scrolling. When I click the button, I want the button to grow and fill almost the entire screen, no matter from where it has to start.

this is the CSS for the standard buttons:

```
.projects .project__button {
  border: var(--color-1) solid .2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3rem;

  color: var(--color-1);

  font-size: 1.5rem;

  cursor: pointer;

  transition: color .2s ease-out, background-color .2s ease-out;
}
.projects .project__button:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: var(--color-1);
}
```

And this is the CSS for the button when clicked:

```
.project .project__button.project__details {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  left: 10vw;

  z-index: 10;

  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;

  background-color: white;
}
```

Is there a workaround to achieve this effect with a transition?
In other words: I need the position to be absolute without using the position property. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS transitions between absolute and relative positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049855/css-transitions-between-absolute-and-relative-positioning)

Comment: Please show us a full example with HTML, e.g. a JSFiddle.

Comment: Sumit Sharma It does not. I viewed that post before posting myself. I cannot use position absolute before the transition.

Comment: Dai here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/mucoLd1y/24/